# Ubuntu Server 17.10 won't autoconfigure ethernet on boot

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

dhclient enables ethernet, with a connection to the internet, but it won't configure automatically.

My NIC is named enp3s0 so I tried adding it to my interfaces as

```
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```

I have no idea what's going on; like I said dhclient has no problem getting connected within seconds, it just won't autoconfigure on a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Networking is handled by netplan by default in Ubuntu Server 17.10. I suggest that you edit the /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml file to read:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
```

Exit and save your changes by running the command:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Please note and follow the spacing and indentation.

Comment out all the enp3s0 stanzas in /etc/network/interfaces. Reboot.

I recommend, however, that you specify a static IP address in a server so that you can easily ssh and ftp into it. The recommended 01-netcfg.yaml file is:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.150/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,192.168.0.1]
```

Of course, substitute your exact details here. Be sure to select an IP address outside the range used for DHCP in the router or access point.